# c++ compile error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying an example from Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ book, third edition. While implementing a rather simple function, I get the following compile time error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
```

What could be causing this? Here is the code. The error is in the `if` line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool accept()
{
    cout << "Do you want to proceed (y or n)?\n";
    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "y") return true;
    return false;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: y in your code is a string literal (double quotes) `""`, a char is only (single quotes) `''`

Comment: Check your typing. The example in Stroustup has `char answer = 0;` and `if (answer == 'y') return true;`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have two ways to fix this. The preferred way is to use:

```
string answer;
```

(instead of `char`). The other possible way to fix it is:

```
if (answer == 'y') ...
```

(note single quotes instead of double, representing a `char` constant).

Answer (score 8):

You need the change those double quotation marks into singles.
ie. `if (answer == 'y')` returns `true`;

Here is some info on String Literals in C++:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: You mean that double quotation marks are not interchangable in c++?

Comment: No, double quotes are `char[]` (a bunch of characters), single quotes is a single `char`.

Comment: just posted a link for you to msdn library.

Answer (score 7):

A string literal is delimited by quotation marks and is of type char* not char.

Example: `"hello"`

So when you compare a char to a char* you will get that same compiling error.

```
char c = 'c';
char *p = "hello";

if(c==p)//compiling error
{
}
```

To fix use a char literal which is delimited by single quotes.

Example: `'c'`

Answer (score 4):

"y" is a string/array/pointer. 'y' is a char/integral type

Answer (score 3):

You must remember to use single quotes for char constants.
So use

`if (answer == 'y') return true;`

Rather than

`if (answer == "y") return true;`

I tested this and it works