# Cannot compare pointer and integer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Hi I am trying to program a simple tic tac toe game, and whenever I compile it says:

```
error: ISO C== forbids comparison between pointer and integer
[-fpermissive]  } while(input != "Quit");
                                 ^
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
Board;
 1 | 2 | 3
---|---|---
 4 | 5 | 6
---|---|---
 7 | 8 | 9
*/

char square[9] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

char input;

void board();

main()
{
    do
    {
        board();
        switch (input)          
        {
            case 1:
                square[1] = 'X';
            case 2:
                square[2] = 'X';
            case 3:
                square[3] = 'X';
            case 4:
                square[4] = 'X';
            case 5:
                square[5] = 'X';
            case 6:
                square[6] = 'X';
            case 7:
                square[7] = 'X';
            case 8:
                square[8] = 'X';
            case 9:
                square[9] = 'X';
            default:
                cout << "Invalid Input";
        }
    } while(input != "Quit");     //Here is where it is an error

    if(input == "Quit")
    {
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "\n\n"; 

    return 0;
}

void board()                //Builds the board
{
    cout << "\n\n\tTicTacToe\n\n";

    cout<<" "<<square[0]<<" | "<<square[1]<<" | "<<square[2]<< endl;
    cout << "---|---|---" << endl;

    cout<<" "<<square[3]<<" | "<<square[4]<<" | "<<square[5]<< endl;
    cout << "---|---|---" << endl;

    cout<<" "<<square[6]<<" | "<<square[7]<<" | "<<square[8]<< endl;

    cout << "Player 1 Make a Move:  ";
    cin.get();
    cin >> input;
}
```

FYI, this isn't close to the full game, I am just trying to figure out how I will code some parts of the game.

Comment: `input` is of type `char` while `"Quit"` is of type `const char *`. You can't compare a character with a string (an array of characters). 
Maybe you are looking for `while(input == 'Q')`

Comment: How do I make "Quit" type const char* ?

Comment: "Quit" is already of type `const char*`, but you need a `char` to be able to compare with `input`, Try using `while(input == 'Q')`

Comment: why does the question end with the words **strong text**?

Comment: You are comparing two different types of values. char and char *

Comment: Also, consider using std::string

Comment: You can replace your `switch` statement with: `if ((input >= 1) && (input <= 9)) square[input] = 'X';`.  By the way, the first cell in an array is 0, as in `square[0]`.  If you want to use indices 1 ... 9, then declare your array with 10 elements (so you are ignoring the element at index 0).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ compile error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263681/c-compile-error-iso-c-forbids-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that variable `input` is declared as a single `char` data type and you're comparing it with a string, or in this case a `const char*`, essentially an array of characters. Since `"Quit"` is an array of characters, you cannot equate that to a SINGLE `char`.

Comment: const char * would give an error in his case, since the input variable cannot be const.

Comment: If you know what I'm saying...he couldn't declare it as const

Comment: @FlareCat I'm only saying its const because its an unchanging, developer defined item that its being used for unchanging comparison.

Comment: Ohh, I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to assign or compare two variables the left operator type must be the same that le right operator type, in your casse le left operator is input, a variable of type char and the left variable type "Quit" is of type const char[4], there two types are different and can't be compare !

Comment: input is not of type int! It is a char

Answer (score 0):

In the if, you are comparing a `char` to `char *`.

Either set the value in the if to

```
'Q'
```

Or declare the input variable using

```
char *input;
```

Consider looking at the string header, it includes features that are highly useful in this situation.

Edit: Another error with your code: In your switch case, you do not include a `break;` after each `case :`. This will cause every everything after the correct case to become `'X'`.

Edit 2: You should NOT use global variables. Just pass them by reference.

Edit 3: main() should have a type.

Answer (score 0):

In your `switch` statement, you are accessing `square[9]` which doesn't exist.  This is called a *buffer overrun* and you may be overwriting other variable or code.

Review with your `board()` function, which accesses the array correctly.

Comment: This is true; his indexing to start at 0.

But, the issue lies in the fact that he is comparing to types of values that cannot be compared, `char *` and `char`.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is `char` and can't be compared with `char*` which is a char pointer.
And please use `std::string` (or `string` in this case) that's an object instead of `char*` which is a primitive type.

It will be something like:

```cpp
string input;
```