# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] [c++]

Tags: c++, string

ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

```
      if(S[i] == "#")
                 ^~~
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string S = "a#b#";
    for( int i=0; i< S.length(); i++){
        if(S[i] == "#")
            //do somethng
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On googling this error i found a workaround to this by using '&' as in `if( &S[i] == "#")` and it works fine. Can someone please enlighten me on why this works, what's happening here ?

Comment: `S[i]` is a character, so it should be compared with an other character, not a string:  
`if(S[i] == '#')`

Comment: dont confuse no compiler errors with "works fine". `if( &S[i] == "#")` is likely not doing what you think it does

Comment: @m88 Thanks. I get it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ compile error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263681/c-compile-error-iso-c-forbids-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're iterating over characters, but you compare the character (char) against (const char *).

You should be comparing it to a character '#'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string S = "a#b#";
    for( int i=0; i< S.length(); i++){
        if(S[i] == '#') // here <--
            //do somethng
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can simplify this to a range based for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string S = "a#b#";
    for(char character : S){
        if(character == '#')
            //do somethng
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

&S[i] == "#" is not as same as s[i]=='#', since former one compares pointer address it evaluates to false.