# comparing cin with strings in cpp

Tags: c++

```
char grade;
cin>>grade;       
if(grade ==  "A"){
  multOfGradeHour += 4.0*creditHour;
}
```

**compare problem**
*I checked at google but did not found any good solution.*
when i enter code here run this code compiler shows me an error.c++ forbids comparison between pointers and integer.i don't understand this because i know nothing about pointers.i tried many things but i did not find any solution for this.anyone who know what to do?

Comment: `'A'` is a character, `"A"` is a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ compile error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263681/c-compile-error-iso-c-forbids-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `"A"` which is a `const char*` (pointer) to a char `A` (which is converted to integer in your original code, therefore the confusing error message from the compiler):

```
char grade;
cin>>grade;       
if(grade == 'A'){
  multOfGradeHour += 4.0*creditHour;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that `"A"` is a [**string literal**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with type `const char[2]` which **decays** to a `const char *`(that is, to a pointer to a `const char`) due to **type decay**.

This means that you are trying to compare a variable named `grade` which is of type `char` with a `const char *` which is what the error says.

##### Solution

To solve this replace `if(grade ==  "A")` with:

```
if(grade ==  'A') //note A is surrounded by single quotes ' ' this time instead of double quotes " "
```

This solution works because this time, `'A'` is a [**character literal**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) and has type `char` which is the same type that variable `grade` has. So, the type of `grade` and `'A'` are the same and hence this works.